# 0x80004005 (Unspecified error) when accessing network share in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares

I'm getting error 0x80004005 when trying to access a network share in Windows 7. The network share was created from a Windows 7 computer and is being accessed by a Windows 7 computer. The same exact configuration worked properly a month ago and for whatever reason doesn't work anymore.

I've tried

- Creating `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` and setting the value to `1`
- Removing all `6to4` adapters in Device Manager
- Disabling IPv6 and setting IPv4 to a static address on the same subnet mask as the other computer
- Verifying the two computers are on the same workgroup
- Disabling the firewall and antivirus
- Updating Windows
- Accessing the share using `\\[IP_ADDRESS]\[SHARE]` and `\\[HOSTNAME]\[SHARE]`
- On the host computer (server) checking `\\localhost` for the share - the share does appear and I can access files
- Enabling NetBIOS over TCP/IP

How can I access this network share? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Recent patches disable SMB v1. Have you tried reenabling it on the guest device?

Comment: Both machines are Windows 7; is that only for Windows 10 machines?

Comment: I had this problem recently on Windows 7. Reason: I had the "Client for Microsoft Networks" component turned off on my LAN properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by installing [KB4487345](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4487345/update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2).

Answer (score 0):

I recently resolved this issue by enabling the following group policy permission:

Local Computer Policy>Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Network>Lanman Workstation>Enable insecure guest logons

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Windows 10, trying to access an open share (without username).

To fix it, you need to enable "AllowInsecureGuestAuth" in the registry under
 "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters".

You can check what it is on your system with

```
reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters /v AllowInsecureGuestAuth
```

And you can set it to enable "AllowInsecureGuestAuth" with

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters /v AllowInsecureGuestAuth /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

You need to do that in a Command Prompt or Powershell started as Admin (or "Run as Administrator")